# IntelliJ Maven where are downloaded sources and documentations

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This may be stupid but I'm following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1sRK8JLCQ4) and he mentions around 26:17 that you can download sources and documentations (if available) for dependencies, and plugins, ...
But he doesn't show where they are downloaded nor how to download them. I've tried downloading them and after several seconds of downloading intelliJ just does some indexing but i can't find the files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are placed next to the library .jar files under Maven home directory (usually `.m2` subdirectory under the user's home directory). You can check the library configuration for the exact location:

[image: sources]

Comment: Thank you!
I've located my files https://i.imgur.com/os0hsnH.png, but what should one do with those files, I've tried running jimfs-1.1-javadoc.jar but nothing happens.

And also, more generally, is this something one does when downloading a new project, i.e. reading the documentations of the dependencies he's never heard of ?

Comment: These files provide sources and documentation for the downloaded libraries so that you can browse the source code in the IDE and view the documentation. You can't run these files.

Comment: How do you view the documentation? I'm a bit confused. Directly in the IDE?

Comment: Please check these help pages for the details how you can view the documentation for the third-party code in your project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs.

Comment: Thank you!
Final question (sorry!!) what exactly is the difference between documentation and source? Is source the source code?

Comment: Yes. it's the source code you can navigate and browse. Documentation is the HTML JavaDoc generated from this source code.

Comment: Any idea why View | External documentation is not showing up (the one they mention in the jetbrains/help you linked): https://i.imgur.com/TQbEXXX.png ?
Maybe i'm hovering the dependency in the pom.xml and not a method used by jimfs ?

Comment: Yes, you need to hover on the class/method usage in the .java file, not in pom.xml.